# How do I play a specific song on a command block without it playing other songs instead?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to select a certain song to play on a command block, but when I type in something like "/playsound music.game.creative @p", it will play a different song everytime I activate the command. Is there a way where I can select one of the songs without it playing a different one?

Comment: This seems to also be a problem in MCJava.

Comment: It seems to only be fixable with a resource pack.